Arabic language writers of Jewish denomination
This is less of a question about Torah, Talmud or similar topics, but more broadly about secular Jewish culture or, let's say, Jewishness in world culture. I didn't find a more appropriate SE community to direct the question.

It is well known the great influence of Jewish secular writers in the German language literature, particularly during the late XIX and early XX c.; to some extent there is also influence in English, mostly in North America, somewhat less in French and a bit in Russian (a few important drops of Italian as well).
Have there been Arabic language writers of Jewish origin, so that one can study the mingling of Jewish themes within Arabic culture and the literature outcome, in a similar manner as it has been studied for instance in German?
I mean writers of the aforementioned period where Modern Standard Arabic was consolidated, not medieval or late medieval Judaeo-Arabic scholars.

They say Baghdad was a quarter Jewish at one point in the 1800s ... but a lot of that history is no longer in vogue ...

@Shalom True. That's one of the motivations of the question.

I vote to keep this question open, because it's not just about jewish writers, but it's about how their writing brought Judaism into other cultures. Given that there were very large Jewish populations in many Arab countries until 1948, it seems like this great question will be receptive to lots of very interesting answers +1. Welcome to Mi Yodeya Daniel Castro, I would ask if you are any relation to the famous Castros, but I wouldn't want to put you on the spot. Regardless, looking forward to learning with you and hope you had a chance to check out the site tour (see the ? button above)

Chaim Nahum,  Chief Rabbi of Egypt from 1923 to 1960, was a prominent Arabist and a founding member of the Royal Academy of the Arabic Language.

I saw the following article by Israeli academic Reuven Snir "Arabic Literature by Iraqi Jews in the Twentieth Century: The Case of Ishaq Bar-Moshe (1927–2003)". Perhaps  other works of the academic can give examples of other writers and better understanding of the question.

.טוב. תודה רבה לך.
